# Keep Getting Permission denied when using fastai library on AWS setting

Tags: amazon-web-services, permission-denied, fast-ai

I'm learning deep learning by taking a lecture that uses fastai. I'm running fastai library on AWS p2.xlarge. When I ran some function on fastai library I get this error.:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-1d86fc0ece07> in <module>()
       1 arch = resnet34
       2 data = ImageClassifierData.from_paths(PATH, tfms=tfms_from_model(arch,sz ))
 ----> 3 learn = ConvLearner.pretrained(arch, data, precompute = True)
       4 learn.fit(0.01, 2)

~/fastai/fastai/conv_learner.py in pretrained(cls, f, data, ps, xtra_fc, xtra_cut, custom_head, precompute, pretrained, **kwargs)
112         models = ConvnetBuilder(f, data.c, data.is_multi, data.is_reg,
113             ps=ps, xtra_fc=xtra_fc, xtra_cut=xtra_cut, custom_head=custom_head, pretrained=pretrained)
 --> 114         return cls(data, models, precompute, **kwargs)
    115 
    116     @classmethod

 ~/fastai/fastai/conv_learner.py in __init__(self, data, models,     precompute, **kwargs)
 95     def __init__(self, data, models, precompute=False, **kwargs):
 96         self.precompute = False
 ---> 97         super().__init__(data, models, **kwargs)
 98         if hasattr(data, 'is_multi') and not data.is_reg and self.metrics is None:
 99             self.metrics = [accuracy_thresh(0.5)] if self.data.is_multi else [accuracy]

 ~/fastai/fastai/learner.py in __init__(self, data, models, opt_fn, tmp_name, models_name, metrics, clip, crit)
 35         self.tmp_path = tmp_name if os.path.isabs(tmp_name) else os.path.join(self.data.path, tmp_name)
 36         self.models_path = models_name if os.path.isabs(models_name) else os.path.join(self.data.path, models_name)
---> 37         os.makedirs(self.tmp_path, exist_ok=True)
 38         os.makedirs(self.models_path, exist_ok=True)
 39         self.crit = crit if crit else self._get_crit(data)

 ~/anaconda3/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/os.py in makedirs(name, mode, exist_ok)
218             return
219     try:
--> 220         mkdir(name, mode)
221     except OSError:
222         # Cannot rely on checking for EEXIST, since the operating system

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'data/dogscats/tmp'
```

I think the AWS console has no permission to make the directory.
I did `sudo mkdir tmp data/dogscats/` but I get another error that I couldn't understand.

I think I have to give AWS some permission but I have no clue how to do that.

I hope you guys can give me some clear idea on how to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: "_I did sudo mkdir tmp data/dogscats/_": I'm not sure if that's a typo, because the error is referring to the directory *data/dogscats/tmp*. Maybe the error that you got with that command is that you entered the command incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Fastai creates saves data like current loss etc. in a folder it creates by default the folder is created in the working directory but you can pass the argument `path` that is the path where you have the privileges to create a folder.